# Como salvar dados em arquivo .txt no VisualG?

Tags: visualg, portugol

Pessoal preciso fazer um sistema de cadastro em Portugol para um trabalho da faculdade. Porém, quero que os dados sejam salvos para uma possível consulta.

Existe a possibilidade de salvar dados em um arquivo .txt no VisualG?

(Pesquisei encontrei o comando "arquivo" mais não entendi como utilizar)

Obrigado!

Comment: tente postar seu código para eu ajuda-lo melhor.

Comment: consegui lhe ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Existe sim a possibilidade de salvar dados em um arquivo em .txt no VisualG! 
O VisuAlg permite o armazenamento de dados em um arquivo-texto, obtendo deles os dados ao executar os comandos `leia`.

Esta característica funciona da seguinte maneira:

(Segundo [esta fonte](http://eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem5.htm))

1. Se não existir o arquivo com nome especificado, o VisuAlg fará uma 
   leitura de dados através da digitação, armazenando os dados lidos neste 
   arquivo, na ordem em que forem fornecidos.
2. Se o arquivo existir, o VisuAlg obterá os dados deste arquivo até chegar 
   ao seu fim. Daí em diante, fará as leituras de dados através da digitação.
3. Somente um comando arquivo pode ser empregado em cada pseudocódigo, e ele 
   deverá estar na seção de declarações (dependendo do "sucesso" desta 
   característica, em futuras versões ela poderá ser melhorada...).
4. Caso não seja fornecido um caminho, o VisuAlg irá procurar este arquivo 
   na pasta de trabalho corrente (geralmente, é a pasta onde o programa 
   VISUALG.EXE está). Este comando não prevê uma extensão padrão; portanto, a 
   especificação do nome do arquivo deve ser completa, inclusive com sua 
   extensão 
   (por exemplo, .txt, .dat, etc.).

A sintaxe do comando é:

```
arquivo < nome-de-arquivo >
```

`<nome-de-arquivo>` é uma constante caractere (entre aspas duplas). Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
  algoritmo "lendo do arquivo"
  arquivo "teste.txt"
  var x,y: inteiro
  inicio
  para x de 1 ate 5 faca
  leia (y)
  fimpara
  fimalgoritmo
```

## EXTRA

Suas variáveis podem também ser armazenadas em uma matriz do tipo caracter e testar ela na consulta e implementar o código com um menu.(Com cadastro e consulta)

```
   algoritmo "lendo do arquivo"
   arquivo "teste.txt"
   var x,y,i,j: inteiro
   char opcao
    vetor mat[5][5]
   inicio
   repita
   escreval("MENU")
   escreval("A- GRAVAR ARQUIVOS")
   escreval("B- PROCURAR ARQUIVOS")
   escreval("s-Sair")
   escolha(opcao)
   caso 'A'
   escreval("Leia matriz:")
   para i de 1 ate 5 faca
   para j de 1 ate 5 faca
   leia(m[i][j])
   fimpara
   fimpara


   caso 'B'
   // compare com a variável que quiser 
   leia(x)
   para i de 1 ate 5 faca
   para j de 1 ate 5 faca
   se(x=m[i][j]) entao
   ...
   fimse
   fimpara
   fimpara
   ate(opcao='s')
   fimescolha
   fimalgoritmo
```

Você pode usar o comando arquivo, porém, talvez não seja a melhor opção.

Pois a cada comando `leia()` que o VisuAlg encontrar, ele vai ficar lendo esse arquivo e jogando na variável que está no `leia()`. Traduzindo... Enquanto não chegar ao fim do arquivo, todo `leia()` vai está direcionado ao arquivo... não será possível ler nenhum dado do usuário via teclado enquanto o arquivo não terminar.

*Se for implementar com arquivo, sempre lembre do comando limpatela talvez seja útil.*